# MySQL Trigger Error using variables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the following code to run in a MySQL Trigger but I get error 1064 when I try to save it.

```
SET @ma = (SELECT modem_alias FROM `play`.`veh` WHERE meid = new.org_a LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO `play`.`des` (`indx`, `des_a`, `des_b`) VALUES (NULL, new.org_a, SELECT @ma);
```

The trigger is set to run on 'org' table after an INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `SELECT` in the `INSERT`, just the variable:

```
INSERT INTO `play`.`des` (`indx`, `des_a`, `des_b`) VALUES (NULL, new.org_a, @ma);
```

You can also combine the two queries so you don't need a variable:

```
INSERT INTO play.des (indx, des_a, des_b)
SELECT NULL, new.org_a, modem_alias
FROM play.veh
WHERE meid = new.org_a
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values is wrong: You can't select there, just use the variable itself:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., @ma);
```